# Django does not save images that i am uploading

Tags: python-3.x, django, storing-data

New to Django.This is my first code.
I am trying to write a code for resturant that takes fields like name, cuisine, price, pic etc. It is supposed to get those fields and files and save it to the media folder. however the code does not work. some of the code is taken from chatgpt as well.

Following is the code for view.py file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Menu
import os
from django.conf import settings
# Create your views here.

class newView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        cuisine = request.POST.get('cuisine')
        price = request.POST.get('price')
        food_type = request.POST.get('food_type')
        desc = request.POST.get('desc')
        pic = request.FILES.get('pic')
        
        context = {
            'menu_items': Menu.objects.all(),
            'message': None
        }

        if not name or not cuisine or not price or not food_type or not desc:
            context['message'] = "Please don't leave any fields empty!!"
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)

        try:
            # Change the uploaded file name
            pic_name = f"{name.replace(' ', '_')}.jpg"  # Assuming the uploaded files are in JPEG format
            m = Menu(name=name, cuisine=cuisine, price=price, food_type=food_type, desc=desc, pic=pic_name)
            print(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, pic_name))
            # Save the file to the storage with the new name
            with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT , pic_name), 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in pic.chunks():
                    f.write(chunk)
            
            m.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            context['message'] = "Duplicate Entry"
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)

        return redirect('index')


    def get(self,request):
        p=Menu.objects.all()
        context={
            'menu_items': p
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html',context)


def delete_item(request,item_name):
    if request.method=="POST":
        try:
            m=Menu.objects.get(name=item_name)
            m.delete()
        except Menu.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return redirect('index')
def home(request):
   
    return render(request,'home.html')

def menu(request):
    menu_items = Menu.objects.all()
    grouped_menu = {}
    
    for item in menu_items:
        if item.food_type in grouped_menu:
            grouped_menu[item.food_type].append(item)
        else:
            grouped_menu[item.food_type] = [item]
    
    context = {
        'grouped_menu': grouped_menu
    }
    
    return render(request, 'menu_template.html', context)
```

NExt file is for the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    food_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="Not Specifiec")
    desc = models.TextField(default="Description Not Available")
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/menu_images/', default='menu_images/default_image.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " : " + self.cuisine
```

tried changing the folder where the images are stored but didn't work

Comment: I would strongly recommend going through with the Django tutorial. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/#first-steps
You will get acquainted with various Django parts like forms, class based views, handling static files. This way you could actually write the basics yourself and get the feeling of how to use Django efficiently.

Comment: ChatGPT is a useful tool. However, blindly taking code from it, might not be the best approach when it comes to understanding the problem.